# Does a pair $(a,b)$ exists, such that both $a$ and $b$ are non-negative, only one of them is a perfect square and their product is a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to have a pair $(a,b)$ where

1. Both $a$ and $b$ are non-negative.
2. One of them is a perfect square and other is not.
3. Their product is $(a,b)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: "perfect and square"?!

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on this problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please, add your effort to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accepted $a,b\in\mathbb Z∪\left\{0\right\}.$

$$a=m^2, m≥0,~ b≥0$$

$$p^2=ab=m^2b$$

- If $m=0$, then $a=0$. This implies, we can always choose $b$, such that $b$ is not a perfect square.
- If $m>0$, then $a=m^2>0$. This implies $b>0$. This follows,

$$ b=\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)^2, m>0, ~p \equiv 0~ (\text{mod}~m)$$

Now, what kind of result can you get from here?

Comment: From you answer i suppose it is not possible to have such a pair...am i right ?

Comment: @Aman No. See my answer "if $m=0$...?$ This is the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer